# adding a case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a table and creating a materialized view for this which will ultimately be hosted as a WMS. Users will click on a polygon and for each polygon this will take them to a url link which is contained within a table called view_params.

The polygon column is called nature_sites, so my current script looks like this:

```
REPLACE ( ( SELECT VALUE FROM view_params 
WHERE parameter = 'nature_sites_url'),
'[nature_sites]',
nature_sites)
```

This works fine but half of the nature_sites do not have a relevant url. How can I write a case statement so that if the value is NOT NULL populate the column otherwise leave blank.

New to oracle/sql so I hope this makes sense.

Comment: That doesn't look like SQL to me. What DBMS are you using.

Comment: Oracle - am niew so maybe I'm using the wrong terminology!

Comment: Thanks JamieA for the response, appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN nature_sites is null THEN '' else REPLACE ( ( SELECT VALUE FROM view_params 
WHERE parameter = 'nature_sites_url'),
'[nature_sites]',
nature_sites) END
```